# Socket.io is super slow when deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, optimization, socket.io

I made a simple game using react and socket.io. You can check that out [here](http://funlastic.herokuapp.com). When I was working on it, it was working fine but when I deployed it on heroku it is running super slow. Each message takes about 2 seconds to get relayed. Please check the [Front-end](https://github.com/Prabodh-Panda/dareee) and [Back-end](https://github.com/Prabodh-Panda/dareee-backend). Please let me know if any file is causing it to slow down or if I have any config errors.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe because socket.io requires sticky sessions and I haven't enabled sticky sessions in heroku????